# How to get the records with mutiple mandatory record values in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm new to kusto functions and i need to get the data for 1 day which should include all the states in that day.
For ex: my raw data looks like the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC9kR.png)

Now I wanted to get the records per day which should have both job states (Running and Completed). Can someone please help me how to get this ?

I should get this one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNBHs.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: it would help if you could provide/clearly describe the expected output (schema & content) given the provided input in the image you've included

Comment: I have updated the ask and added output screenshot. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start with a [Kusto query language tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer), or try out the [Kusto Query Language learning module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/write-first-query-kusto-query-language/). For this question, it seems that you are looking for a filter for a specific day. Here is an example:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, State:string, Id:string)[datetime(2021-11-28 07:05:14.2448699), "Completed", "a",
             datetime(2021-11-28 05:05:14.2448699), "Running", "a",
             datetime(2021-11-29 04:06:12.2448699), "Running", "b",
             datetime(2021-11-29 09:15:11.2448699), "Completed", "b",
             datetime(2021-11-30), "Completed", "c",
             datetime(2021-11-30 07:05:14.2448699), "Completed", "c"];
T 
| where Timestamp between(datetime(2021-11-29) .. endofday(datetime(2021-11-29)))
```

| Timestamp | State | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-29 04:06:12.2448699 | Running | b |
| 2021-11-29 09:15:11.2448699 | Completed | b |